# Django: overwriting model's ID

Tags: python, django

I have a basic question and I think the answer should be obvious, but I couldn't find it myself. This is my model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
   name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'')
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Lets say there are 3 Topic object instances with such ID's:

1
2
3

When I `delete()` the 3rd instance and try to create a new one, Django gives an ID of '4' to the last instance, but I would like to measure all present Topic's ID's and give the new object ID of `highest present ID +1`, for example:

Topic---ID

Topic1--1

Topic2--2

Topic3--3

And when I delete Topic3 (id=3) and create new Topic Topic4, I would like that the ID for it would be 3.

It is possible to do it via Django shell, I am just not sure how should I overwrite model's ID creation method.

When I am creating `Topic` I am creating it for current logged in user (`user = request.user`) and under current Subject (`subject = slug`)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just let the database manage the ids. It doesn't matter if there are gaps.

Comment: It is required by my App's business logic. I am dynamically creating objects with Jquery and Ajax and the links like (http://example.com/app/edit/topic/<PK>) should be dynamic - PK+1 and etc.

Comment: The fact that the `PK` is used in your URL does not in any way require them to be contiguous, nor does the presence of AJAX in your application.

Comment: Unfortunately my app requires that. For example when I am creating a dynamic Topic (my App tries to avoid page refreshing as much as possible) I have to specify a dynamic link to edit it. I am parsing html and looking at the previous present topic and generating link of example.com/app/edit/topic/pk+1. If there will be a gap of PK's it will throw an object does not exist error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app logic definitely does not require this. You have made a mistake in assuming that you could parse the HTML of your template, increment the value you found, and expect to find something in the database with this ID. Rather than trying to micromanage the database to deal with this, let's walk back your decision and consider an alternative.

When you dynamically create a Topic, do it this way:

1. Make an AJAX call to the server with the new Topic's information.
2. Have a view handle the AJAX call and create the view, responding with its newly minted pk.
3. Dynamically generate a URL using the `pk` you got back in, presumably, `JSON`.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds logical! I will see how it goes and update the problem status.

Comment: This method works fine as it should, thank you again for your help. I guess it is sometimes better not to over-complicate everything.